Why is my voltage follower (buffer) not working?
I'm building a voltage follower with an LM358. I'm taking a 60 Hz, 5.0 Vrms signal from my signal generator.  I want the 5 volts drop across a 10 ohm load.
I'm trying to use an LM358 as a voltage follower to buffer the load. You can see my setup below. I'm feeding the Vcc into pin 8 and GND to pin 4. I connected the signal to the non-inverting input (in 3) and connected the inverting input (pin 2) to the output (pin 1). I connected the output to the load.
I'm feeding 12 Vcc to the rails of the op amp, but I'm barely reading 0.1 volts across the 10 ohms load. I believe all the connections are right, so why isn't the buffer working?




10 Ohms is the main problem. Opamp cannot drive such a low resistance, try 1k instead.   Also, single supply is also a problem

Use always power supplies capacitor decoupling ...

You will need one of these. ;) Not exactly cheap. But capable.


I want the 5 volts drop across a 10 ohm load.

That means a current of 500 mA.
The TI LM358 datasheet shows the Output current specification as:

Therefore, the LM358 is unable to supply the required current for the 10 ohm load. Therefore, try a larger load resistor.

Is there an OP amp that can supply 500 mA?

Not only is LM358 too feeble to supply required current, but a single-supply to pin 8 won't allow function generator peaks that go below ground. You'd want a  +/- DC power supply. ( "+" to pin 8, "-" to pin 4). There are some integrated circuits meant for driving speakers that might be suitable instead.

The op-amp cannot produce an output potential which falls outside its own power supply potentials. From your description I assume that the op-amp's positive supply rail is +12V, and its negative supply rail is 0V. For this particular op-amp, the LM358, this will impose the following constraint on output voltage:
$$ 0V < V_{OUT}< +10.5V $$
The output can never become more negative than its own negative power supply pin, 0V in this case. See page 4 of the LM358 datasheet, parameters "Output Voltage - High Limit" and "Output Voltage - Low Limit".
Input voltages have similar constraints. The LM358 is fine with input potentials right down to its negative supply rail (0V in this case), but inputs must not fall below that. Your schematic makes it immediately clear that you are applying periodically negative potentials to the inverting input. That's a violation of the op-amps acceptable input voltage range. See page 4 of the datasheet, a parameter called "Input Common Mode Voltage Range".
These input and output voltage range problems are trivial to solve, by providing a negative power supply to the op-amp, so that the supplies are +12V and −12V.
A third issue you must contend with is the maximum output current that the LM358 can provide. A sinusoidal 5V RMS signal has peaks and troughs of \$\pm 5V\times \sqrt{2} = \pm 7V\$. Across a 10Ω load, this corresponds to a current of:
$$ I_{OUT} = \pm \frac{7V}{10\Omega} = \pm 700mA $$
You are asking the LM358 to alternately sink and source up to 700mA, which is impossible. The most you can get out of that little thing is about 20mA. This information is found on page 5 of the datasheet, described by parameters "Output Source Current" and "Output Sink Current". It's generally not advisable to approach these maxima, because output voltage swing tends to suffer.
Limited output current is a much more difficult problem to solve. A small number of so-called "power op-amps" exists that are capable of sourcing and sinking 700mA or more, but if you're stuck with a puny "signal" op-amp like the LM358, then you'll need some transistors to "boost" current:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I've used Q1 and Q2 in a "push-pull" arrangement to provide 99% of the required output current directly from the power supplies, rather than the op-amp. The LM358 is now tasked with providing only a small fraction of that. Negative feedback comes from the overall output, not the op-amp's own output, so closed-loop gain is still exactly 1, and this whole system is still a precise voltage follower.
Caveat: Transistors Q1 and Q2 will dissipate several watts of power, and will get hot very quickly. Without some beefy heat-sinks they won't last very long.

500 mA opamp manufacturers:  Analog Devices, Linear Technology, National Semiconductor, Apex, Burr Brown, Texas Instruments.  Some of these companies have been bought by others, but these are the names that come to mind.
You don't say anything about the frequency range of your input signal.  Depending on that, it might be easier to use a small (3 W or larger), audio power amplifier chip.  SGS is big in this field.  The TDA2002 is ancient, but available, reliable, and has tons of documentation.  And, it is designed for single-supply operation.  There are many more options in the TA product line.
Sticking to an audio approach, there are many pre-built modules on ebay and Alibaba, any one of which costs less than what you would pay for just the parts.
Please update your question with the input signal frequency range, and characteristics of the signal source such as its output impedance.

Here is one way to get a 5Vrms output (not necessarily very low distortion) across a 10Ω load resistor, provided the resistor does not need to be grounded, using the LM358.
The input voltage has been halved to 3.535V peak (2.5Vrms) since the circuit has a gain of 2.

Alternatively, provide a -12V supply and use a simple buffered voltage follower:

At higher frequencies you'll start to see visible crossover distortion, but at 60Hz it's not too bad.
The top circuit is okay without heat sinks on the 4 power transistors (about 0.6W each), the bottom one may need a small heat sink on each of the two (about 1.5W each).
